# Send two parameters to the same scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

I have a small doubt, a scope can receive more than 1 parameter? I'm trying something like this but it marks me error:

I call it this way in the controller:

```
@search_productos_out = Producto.without_grupo(params[:id],params[:IdEmpresa])
```

this is the scope:

```
scope :without_grupo, -> (id_grupo, id_empresa) {Producto.includes(:relprogrupos).references(:relprogrupos).where("relprogrupos.id IS NULL OR productos.Clave not in (select distinct ProductoId from relprogrupos where IdGrupo = ?) AND relprogrupos.IdEmpresa != ?", id_grupo, id_empresa)}
```

the error:
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)

Comment: Your error says "(given 1, expected 2)", not "(given 2, expected 1)"... are you using it the old way somewhere still?

Comment: As an aside, that's not really a scope as it is currently written, it is just a plain old class method that is abusing `scope`.

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :without_grupo, lambda {|id_grupo, id_empresa| where("relprogrupos.id IS NULL OR productos.Clave not in (select distinct ProductoId from relprogrupos where IdGrupo = ?) AND relprogrupos.IdEmpresa != ?", id_grupo, id_empresa)}
```

call it like :

```
Producto.includes(:relprogrupos).references(:relprogrupos).without_grupo(id_grupo, id_empresa)
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this as a class method. It's still chainable, and used like the scope way.

```
def self.without_grupo(id_grupo, id_empresa)
  Producto.includes(:relprogrupos)
          .references(:relprogrupos)
          .where("relprogrupos.id IS NULL OR productos.Clave not in (select distinct ProductoId from relprogrupos where IdGrupo = ?) AND relprogrupos.IdEmpresa != ?", id_grupo, id_empresa)
end
```